# Loop through list of objects and change by reference in data.table

Tags: r, data.table, eval

I have a list of `data.table` objects that all have a similar name and some property that I would like to change on all of them by looping through this list. Let's consider this:

```
set.seed(999)
GenName_ksio3k_F1 <-data.table(Risknr = runif(10,1000,9999), Code=LETTERS[sample.int(10)], val=rnorm(10));GenName_ksio3k_F1
GenName_kf0bner_F6 <-data.table(Risknr = runif(10,1000,9999), Code=LETTERS[sample.int(10)], val=rnorm(10));GenName_kf0bner_F6
GenName_sjkw_F2 <-data.table(Risknr = runif(10,1000,9999), Code=LETTERS[sample.int(10)], val=rnorm(10));GenName_sjkw_F2
```

So as suggested by this naming, these objects have similar names which I can capture conveniently in a list via regular expression:

```
list =  grep("^(GenName_).*(F[0-9])$", ls(), perl=TRUE, value=TRUE);list
```

Now, what I would like to to do is change the column `Risknr` to a factor variable on all of these tables. I tried this:

```
    for(DT in list){
      print(str(eval(parse(text = DT)))) # as a test
      eval(parse(text = DT))$Risikonr <- as.factor(eval(parse(text = DT$Risikonr)
}
```

accessing the variable seems to work, as printing `str` for each `DT` shows. The `as.factor`-conversion looks wrong and of course does not work. 
But how to do this?

Comment: `lapply(list, function(i) {i$Risknr <- as.factor(i$Risknr);i})`

Comment: `list2env(lapply(mget(list), function(x) x[, Risknr := factor(Risknr)]))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `get` to get the value, and if we need to update use `assign`

```
for(DT in list){
    assign(DT, value = get(DT)[, Risknr := factor(Risknr)])

}

str(GenName_sjkw_F2)
#Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  10 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ Risknr: Factor w/ 10 levels "1899.01318506384",..: 4 9 7 5 1 3 2 10 8 6
# $ Code  : chr  "G" "B" "A" "E" ...
# $ val   : num  -0.1167 -0.645 1.7444 0.3661 -0.0668 ...
# - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
str(GenName_kf0bner_F6)
#Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  10 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ Risknr: Factor w/ 10 levels "1497.60077643953",..: 2 10 9 7 6 5 8 4 3 1
# $ Code  : chr  "H" "F" "B" "G" ...
# $ val   : num  2.383 0.601 0.179 1.081 -0.247 ...
# - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

However, it is better to have datasets in a `list` instead of multiple global objects